# Get location of a solution/project in VS project template Wizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package, project-template

I am implementing a Wizard for a project template and I would like to get the project/solution path that the user has selected in the New project window. I know that there are certain parameters like $saferootprojectname$ to get the name of the project but no idea how to get the location path

Regards

Answer (score 5):

on RunStarted method, use replacementsDictionary["$destinationdirectory$"] contains the destination directory.

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string,string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams) 
{    
     string Path=replacementsDictionary["$destinationdirectory$"];

}
```

You can use "$destinationdirectory$" in your generated code files.

I found this answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fce79568-121e-4fba-adfa-d127f51b3483/accessing-new-project-dialog-values-in-runstarted)